# Discourse plugin - sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, discourse

In my plugin for [Discourse](https://meta.discourse.org) I am trying to send an email to a user.

This works just fine if I hardcode my own API functionality to do so, however in an effort to make this public I was trying to use the built in emailing. I cannot however get an email to send.

I have tried:

```
def self.send_user_email(address)
  message = Mail::Message.new(from: "from@fromEmail.com", to: address, body: "hello")
  Email::Sender.new(message, :admin_login).send # I used admin_login as according to the spec it should send even if email is disabled. 
end
```

When I do this however I am getting an error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `deliver_now' for #<Mail::Message:0x007fa1bf157300>
Did you mean?  deliver:
  mail (2.6.6) lib/mail/message.rb:1379:in `method_missing'
```

So if I go and update [line 184](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/lib/email/sender.rb#L184) of sender.rb in Discourse to use `#deliver` instead of `#deliver_now`, I am able to get it to kinda try to send an email on my development environment.

Answer (score 0):

**Rails 4.2** deprecated `deliver` / `deliver!` in favor of `deliver_now` / `deliver_now!`. ([Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16582))
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#action-mailer-deprecations

**Rails 5.0** removed deprecated `deliver` and `deliver!` methods. ([commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/755dcd0691f74079c24196135f89b917062b0715))
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#action-mailer-removals

---

This is the reason why you are getting the error. Rails applications >= 5.0 will have this error until the source code you referred to is updated.